# a tag 404 error when trying to make a download link

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a download link for my resume, I keep getting a 404 error page not found, when i expected a download. how do i fix this ?

```
<ul className='flex items-center'>
  <li>
    <BsFillMoonStarsFill className='cursor-pointer text-2xl' />
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='public/Resume/Heather_ChristensenHarper_Resume.pdf' className='bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-teal-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-m-8 ml-8'>
      Resume
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try adding `/` at the start of `href`.

Comment: nope did not work, Ive tried adding ,/ and / no go

Comment: Basically, the error means your URL is not correct. Hover your mouse over the link and see what's the URL and make it correct.

Comment: I did that, I copied relative path as well. Still not working

Comment: What's the full URL you're seeing?

Comment: This is how I fixed it ::   I had to import my resume up top and then:                         <li>
               
<a  className='bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-teal-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md ml-8' href="/resume/Heather_ChristensenHarper_Resume.pdf" download><strong>Download my Resume!</strong></a></li>

Comment: You need to provide the path from which your browser can access the file

Answer (score 0):

Don't include public.

```
<a href="/Resume/Heather_ChristensenHarper_Resume.pdf"/>
```

^ should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it :: I had to import my resume up top and then:

```
 <li> <a className='bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-teal-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md ml-8' href="/resume/Heather_ChristensenHarper_Resume.pdf" download><strong>Download my Resume!</strong></a></li>
```